# replace something in a string with something else in JS

Tags: javascript, string, replace

First part:

I want to replace the spaces in a string to \n but the first space I want it to be replaced with a double like this: \n\n

```
var string = "this is something random “
```

Result needed:

```
var string = "this\n\nis\nsomething\nrandom\n"
```

Second part:

I want to replace the string quotes with backticks.

```
var string =  "this\n\nis\nsomething\nrandom\n"
```

Result needed:

```
var string = `this\n\nis\nsomething\nrandom\n`
```

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? You should try finding a solution to your problem and post your code if it doesn´t work

Comment: For the second part I have tried string.replace('"', "`") but it doesn’t work so it wont work either for the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Part**
For what you want, you can just call a replace function to replace the first occurrence, then a replaceAll/regex to replace all others:

```js
let input = "Hello World !"

function replaceFirstThenAll(string, lookfor, replace) {
    return string
      // replace the first occurance
      .replace(lookfor, replace.repeat(2))
      // now all others
      .replace(new RegExp(lookfor, 'g') /* global regex */, replace)
}

console.log(replaceFirstThenAll(
    input,
    " ", 
    "\n"
)) // Hello\n\nWorld\n !
```

**Second Part**
The way that you declare a string doesn't matter in js, so there's no way to replace it. No matter which method you use, the string is the same.

```js
"String1" == 'String1' // true
'String2' == `String2` // true
```

Comment: In regards to the second part I am trying to pass the value into a js library and when I use "" or '' it doesn’t work.. it only works when I use `` for some reason…

Comment: @ETHERC20 are you using another string then what's provided in the example? If so, could you please send it. You could be having an issue like this, where the use of a ' ends the string without intention: `'I don't like cookies'`

Comment: you are actually right it doesn’t matter wether its `` or " I just tried it. How weird I tried before and it didn’t work I guess I missed maybe something else.